# wordpress- woocommerce add an optional product at checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for one of my websites.Now i want to add an optional (checkbox) 1$ product at the checkout page. If checked ,1$ will be added to the total payment or else as it is. 
Do i need to use some extra add-on plugin for this functionality ?.
Any advice will be highly helpful.
Thank you

Comment: seems like nobody has any clue about it..

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this too. An optional addons to the main product, all that I've found is official woocommerce plugin (Woocommerce Product Addons) http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/